# Prove identity involving resultant of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, resultant

Consider polynomials $f,g \in k[x]$ of positive degrees $m,n$ respectively. Let $I$ denote the ideal in $k[x]$ generated by $f$, and let $\mu$ denote the multiplication map

$$\mu:k[x]/I \to k[x]/I,h+I \mapsto gh+I$$

Demonstrate that $res_x(f,g)=LC(f)^{\deg(g)}\det(\mu)$.

Now the resultant is the determinant of the corresponding Sylvester matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
f_m & f_{m-1} & \cdots  &        & f_0 &  & &  \\
    & f_m     & f_{m-1} & \cdots & & f_0 &  &  \\
    &         & \ddots  &        & & & \ddots &   \\
    &         &         & f_m    & f_{m-1} &\cdots & & f_0  \\
g_n & g_{n-1} & \cdots  &        & g_0 &  & &  \\
    & g_n     & g_{n-1} & \cdots && g_0 & &  \\
    &         & \ddots  &        & & & \ddots &  \\
    &         &         & g_n    & g_{n-1} & \cdots  & & g_0  \\
\end{pmatrix}$

The determinant can be calculated using Laplace expansion. If we start at $f_m=LC(f)$ then we can do a Laplace expansion exactly $\deg(g)$ times (along the diagonal). However if we do the Laplace expansion always for the first column of the new submatrix then we also have the $g_n$'s in the new submatrices?

Also I struggle to understand what the determinant of a multiplication map is. I've read that it involves something with bases but I don't really understand that.

Any help would be appreciated!